# Emergency Field Amputation in a Last Resort Scenario

Tags: bleeding, amputation, stitches

How would it go down to give the victim the best chance of surviving if it was absolutely necessary to perform an amputation in the field. I have read multiple articles that say that cauterizing is likely not a good idea. Some said you have to find and tie off blood vessles before closing. If a civilian were to have to do this in an emergency where no hospital would be available ever, what would be the way to go about it and care for it afterwards that gives the best chance of survival for the patient? Disclaimer: While this is something I'd like to know because I think it's interesting, I know that this is never something that should ever be attempted outside of an absolute last resort scenario.

I was asked to add links to the things I've looked at to show that I've tried to answer the question for myself. I'll provide some links below. Thank you so much for your patience and your time reading this.

Sources:
This is a video on youtube of a field amputation. (Gore warning, incase I need that.) I'm not really sure how the patient would be cared for afterwards though if there were no hospital which is a big part of my question. I couldn't find a single thing to address that unfortunately.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zP7i6LvdaPg&ab_channel=MedicalCollegeofWisconsin

This is an article about what to do in the case of accidental amputation. It covers that one should apply a tourniquet and stop the bleeding until emergency services arrive
[https://www.ems1.com/ems-products/bleeding-control/articles/how-to-manage-traumatic-amputations-and-uncontrolled-bleeding-DXMXDz8EQiT2dvfd/#:~:text=Control%20bleeding%20and%20bandage%20the,container%20or%20resealable%20plastic%20bag](https://www.ems1.com/ems-products/bleeding-control/articles/how-to-manage-traumatic-amputations-and-uncontrolled-bleeding-DXMXDz8EQiT2dvfd/#:%7E:text=Control%20bleeding%20and%20bandage%20the,container%20or%20resealable%20plastic%20bag)

In the interest of not posting too many sources, this is the last one I'll put up here, though I promise it's far from the last one I waded through. I actually found this on Wikipedia. I post it because it gave a very slight description of what might happen afterward. It was still very vague though. It actually said that doctors might leave the wound open for awhile with a sterile dressing, but didn't really describe how they would decide whether to do that or for how long they would keep it that way. https://www.webmd.com/a-to-z-guides/definition-amputation

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in the [help] and the[reasons mentioned in [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.

Comment: @CareyGregory Thank you so much for your feedback. I'm so sorry I messed the question up. I tried to show that I had done research by mentioning what other articles had said, but it was silly not to include some sources. Is this better? I can post more sources I had looked at too but I was worried about it becoming too long.

Comment: You didn't mess anything up. Your edits are fine, thank you.